# Load images into tensorflow from a single directory, with classes specified in a csv file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let's say I have a single directory `data`, which has pictures of both cats and dogs and a separate csv file `labels.csv`, which has the names of the files in the directory and it's labels. How can I load this image dataset into tensorflow?

csv:

```
| filename |  label  |
|__________|_________|
|  a.png   |   cat   |
|  b.png   |   dog   |
|__________|_________|
```

Most of the image classification tutorials in keras' website or tensorflow's website use the `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`, but it needs images to be in separate folders.

Comment: Well, it seems I would have to write my own "data input pipeline". I think I am getting the hang of it. Will answer it here as soon as I finish it.

Comment: just use ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe

Comment: That's helpful. Will try. Thanks @GerryP

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution in terms of memory consumption or some other parameter, but it works and this is what I'm using right now. I am not going to accept my own answer to welcome better answers. If I happen to write a better solution, I will add another answer.

The approach here is simple. We create two functions, one to get the numpy array with a file name and an another to get the label with a file name. Then load the filenames in a list. Then for all files in the list, we get a pair of numpy array (image data) and the label and feed it to `tensorflow`. I'm going to ignore importing libraries for brevity and because it is fairly obvious what libraries are being used.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("labels.csv")
filenames = glob.glob("data/*")

def get_nparray_from_filename(filename):
    img = PIL.Image.open(filename)
    img_array = np.asarray(img)
    return img_array

def get_label_from_filename (filename):
    filename = filename.split("/")[1] # only get the filename (ignore data/)
    df_row = df.loc[df['filename'] == filename
    cat_dog = 0 # cat = 0, dog = 1
    try:
        value = df_row['label'].iloc[0]
        cat_dog = 1 if value == "dog" else 0
    except:
        print(f"{filename} has no entry in the csv")
    return cat_dog

dataset = []
labels = []

for file in filenames:
    npa = get_nparray_from_filename(file)
    lab = get_label_from_filename(file)
    dataset.append(npa)
    labels.append(lab)

# test_train_split from scikit-learn
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Convert to pure numpy array to prevent tensorflow crash
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = np.asarray(x_train), np.asarray(x_test), np.asarray(y_train), np.asarray(y_test)

# Viola, we have loaded our data into tensorflow.
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test))
```

Comment: I was watching a tutorial and the guy in that video uses nearly the same method as above to load labels from a dataframe. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hraKTseOuJA) is the video and [here](https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/142-multi_label_classification.py) is the code.